# Instagram Realtime Tag API w/private users

Tags: api, security, tags, real-time, instagram

I know there are reports of various issues when trying to pull pictures posted by 'private' users. We are working on a project that we want to use the real-time api for. After a private user approves our account, we are able to view images posted by them through the api's as expected.  In addition when searching by tag we see their images.  The real-time API reports the image when we subscribe to the user endpoint.  We want to subscribe to the tag api, the issue is that while everything else works with private users, for some reason when a private user posts an image with a tag for which our client has subscribed, the notification is not set.  It is working fine for public users, and if we search (without real-time notification) we are able to see the image.   The only thing I can think of is that for search to work we must use our access key for our account (not the posters), not our clientid, perhaps real-time needs to use the same security by accesskey rather than client id?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct:

> we must use our access key for our account (not the posters), not our clientid

Because the privacy permissions are per-account, if you are making authenticated API calls on behalf of the user, this will not work. In theory, if you kept your hourly API calls under the 5000 limit, you *could* technically proxy or cache the private photos, however, rather than looking at a complicated workaround, you're better to just adhere to the [API ToU](http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/):

> If your application has any cached copies of User Content that has become "private," you must remove such User Content as soon as reasonably possible.

The realtime API is a bit different than the regular API as well, in that while you may or may not receive a notification of a post (it's not the most reliable service), it does't contain any data, and you're still going out to fetch the relevant data using either your own access_token, your app client_id/secret, or an authenticated user token.

Comment: I totally agree with what you point out regarding removing private pictures and the security.  My question is regarding the real-time API, it appears that even when my client ID has access to the private user (eg they have been approved).  When we subscribe to the tag endpoint, we do not recieve any realtime notification when the private user posts.  We could subscribe to both tag and user at the same time, that would capture both, but then we would recieve notification for every post by the private user, not just posts with the tag we are looking for.  Once we get the rt ping, we can search.

Comment: The way they handle the privacy is a bit weird. Tagged photos appear in the tag stream even if the user is private, while user feeds do not. But client_id/client_secret are *app* level tokens, so thats why it gives the appearance of having access to the private user, when in fact you're just receiving the RT notification of the unprivatized, tagged photo. That make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, however what we are seeing is different than you describe.  Looking at realtime alone, if I setup a "user" rt feed, i get notifications regardless of the users privacy settings, this makes perfect sense.  The issue comes into play with the "tag" feed, if setup a feed for a tag eg "testing123" users who post with this tag trigger a ping, however users who are private do not, even if my account is both an approved follower of the and if they have signed up for our app.  Hopefully that is clear, it seems like private user's never send data to the tag realtime feed.